# How do I add numbers in a list that do not equal parameters?

Tags: python, list, parameters, sum

I am trying to write a function that will add all of the numbers in a list that do not equal the parameters.  The code I have, that is not working, is:

```
def suminout(nums,a,b):
    total=0
    for i in range(len(nums)):
        if nums[i]!=a or nums[i]!=b:
            total=total+nums[i]
    return total
```

It appears to be summing everything in the list.

For example, if I called:
suminout([1,2,3,4],1,2)
it should return 7.  However, I am getting 10.

Any thoughts?

Comment: You need `and` instead of `or`. Or just do `sum(i for i in nums if not i in {a, b})`

Comment: @Kasramvd I think you meant to put a and b in a tuple and not a dict. That is adding a syntax error in your code.

Comment: @euphoria83 `{a, b}` is a [set](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `and` instead of `or`.

```
def suminout(nums,a,b):
    total=0
    for i in range(len(nums)):
        if nums[i]!=a and nums[i]!=b:
            total=total+nums[i]
    return total
```

Your `for` logic could be further simplified (without using `len()` and `range()`) as:

```
for num in nums:
    if num not in [a, b]:  # same as: num != a and num != b
        total += num  # same as: total = total + num
```

Better way to achieve it using `list comprehension` with `sum()` as mentioned by Sean. OR you may use [`filter()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter) instead of list comprehension:

```
>>> my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> sum(filter(lambda x: x !=1 and x!=4, my_list))
5
```

Answer (score 1):

As Kasramvd so duly noted, you need conjunction not disjunction.

Here is a list comprehension doing the same thing.

```
def suminout(nums, a, b):
    total = 0
    total = sum([x for x in nums if (x!=a and x!=b)])
    return total
```

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri I am aware. Just making it analogous to OPs question.

Comment: I do not think it is because of maintaining the analogous code. If it was, you wouldn't have used `sum()` and would have pointed just the error. I agree, `sum()` is the better way to achieve this result. And if you are using that, `total  = 0` is not required. That was my point.

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri That's fine.

Answer (score 0):

Or:

```
def suminout(nums, a, b):
    total = 0
    total = sum([x for x in nums if x not in (a,b)])
    return total
```